# Formato de moeda

Tags: mysql, sql

Para ficar completo não poderia entrar com um FORMAT(Valor,2) inclusive no CONCAT?

```
SELECT * , CONCAT('de ', Valor, ' por ', desconto) AS promocao  
FROM (SELECT Valor, Valor - Valor * 20/100 AS desconto  
FROM comissao 
ORDER BY comissao.Valor DESC) t;
```

Na página o resultado da coluna "promocao" da CONCAT fica sem formatação como por exemplo:
"de 14230 por 11384' seria melhor 14.230,00 e os desconto de 20% ficando 11.384,00.

Comment: A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para aceitá-la. Assim poderá utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `FORMAT` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT t.*,
       CONCAT('de ', FORMAT(t.valor, 2, 'de_DE'), ' por ', FORMAT(t.desconto, 2, 'de_DE')) AS promocao  
  FROM (SELECT c.Valor as valor,
               c.valor - c.valor * 20/100 AS desconto
          FROM comissao c
         ORDER BY c.valor DESC) t;
```

O resultado da coluna promoção seria:

> de 14.230,00 por 11.384,00

Quanto a função:

> **[`FORMAT(X,D[,locale])`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format)**
>
> Formats the number X to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to D decimal places, and returns the result as a string. If D is 0, the result has no decimal point or fractional part.
>
> The optional third parameter enables a locale to be specified to be used for the result number's decimal point, thousands separator, and grouping between separators. ... . If no locale is specified, the default is 'en_US'.

Ou em tradução livre:

> Formata um número X para um formato '#,###,###.##' arredondando para as casas decimais D, e retorna o resultado como string. Se D for 0, o resultado não tem casas decimais.
>
> O terceiro parâmetro (opcional) habilita a especificação da localidade usada para determinar o separador decimal, o separador de milhares e o agrupamento entre separadores do resultado. ... . Se nenhum local for especificado, o padrão é 'en_US'.

Utilizei a localidade `de_DE` porque a Alemanha utiliza o padrão internacional que é o mesmo que utilizamos e o `pt_BR` não trazia o separador de milhares.

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certo.